# How to access class property in method

Tags: php, class, methods, properties

i have the following code:

```
class FanClub_Banner
{
    public $img = 'http://www.example.com/museum/images/logo_ver_250.png';

    public static function banner_me(array $widget, $positionCode, array $params, XenForo_Template_Abstract $renderTemplateObject)
    {
        return '<img src="'. $this->$img . '" width="250" height="250" alt="Museum">';
    }
}
```

and i get the error:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\public_html\comunidad\library\FanClub\Banner.php on line 8
```

How to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your static method cannot access your Class property, a simple fix would be to remove the `static` from `public static function` and where you want to use this method you'd do `FanClub_Banner fcBanner = new FanClub_Banner();
fcBanner->banner_me(....);`

Another fix would be to make the property static as well so you'd have `public static $img...`